# Rails - raw() removing FORM from content field data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, wysiwyg

I have a text field that stores page content created with a WYSIWYG HTML Editor.

## Text field (content):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/myaction" method="post">
<input name="myaction[product]" type="hidden" value="Other" /> 
<input name="myaction[product]" type="hidden" value="Car" /> 
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Get a Car"/>
</form>
```

## Show page

```
<% highlight(raw(@page.content),params[:search]) %>
```

The form does not seem to display or show the bootstrap form and button. It seems to be getting removed. What can I do to get the form to display?

Comment: try `<%= raw(@page.content) %>` ?

Comment: Khiav, I have the <%= %> brackets. The content shows, but strips the form, and it also strips my embedded videos.  Actually my exact code is      <%= highlight(raw(@page.content),params[:search]) %>  Maybe the highlight is doing something?